# Access action-helper inside front-controller plugin

Tags: zend-framework, helper, front-controller

I am trying to call a view of helper from a plug in(registered in bootstrap). From any controller i am able to access without any issue but not from a plugin. Below is my code. Any help is appreciated.
thank you. Miguel

```
class Plugins_security extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $moduleName = $request->getModuleName();
        if ($request->getModuleName() != "auth") 
        {
            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            if (! $auth->hasIdentity()) 
            {
                $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
                'redirector');
                $flashMessenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessages');
                $flashMessenger->flashMessenger (array('message' => 'Sessao expirada', 'status' => 'error'));
                $redirector->gotoUrl('/auth/login/')->redirectAndExit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error.
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'FlashMessages' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_: Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/' in /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:412 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(366):

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

**Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessages');**

to

**Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');**

Example:

$flashMessenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');
$flashMessenger->addMessage(array('error' => 'Session expired'));

Hope this helps you. Not tested

Comment: FlashMessenger is not the name of my helper the name is FlashMessages and within that class i call:
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');

Comment: Then you need to register your helper FlashMessages in application bootstrap before Plugins_security register. So that it can be available.

Comment: how do you register a view helper.I am able to to acccess this helper throughout the application but not within plugin class.

Comment: First FlashMessenger is not a view helper it is an action helper. we register plugin like this  protected function _initPlugins() {
  //YOUR ACTION HELPER SHOULD BE REGISTER HERE BEFORE   $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
  $front->registerPlugin(new Custom_Plugin_PluginName());
 }